# Bend object with curves modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, nurbs-surface

I'm trying to make Wheat

[image]

How to bend this object without affecting target size?

When I add this Object in *Curve* modifier with NurbsPath in object section
my object changes sizes and moves, looking broken.

Screenshot broken object 
http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4GtSJ-MipyWVWRyZkNncTRFWWs/view?usp=sharing

[image: Screenshot broken object]

Broken Wheat
http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4GtSJ-MipyWTDZ3V0l0OHNnTFE/view?usp=sharing

[image]

I tried select nurbs, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose *Scale* and *Rotation*, and object still resizes and looks broken

Here is my project file

[image]

Comment: attach your blend file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: done, any solution??

Comment: The problem is solve for the resize ctrl+A apply all scale+rotation+location it will scale as its normal but a new problem arise its modifier disable

Comment: i got the solution but how can i write the answer the below text is disappear to attach the file

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos why the below answer panel is disappear to give the answer

Comment: This question is marked as duplicate, there already is an answer.